# Where is the ipad table view row insert icon located

Tags: xcode, icons, tableview

I've been searching the .png files on my Mac looking for the iPad Table View row insert icon (a white plus sign on a green background surrounded by a gray circle). I'd like to use it in a custom table view that inserts records. Is it possible to find that particular icon from Apple on my computer? Is the fact that it's not easy to find a hint that perhaps I shouldn't use it?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the `UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert` button:

[image: UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert]

Comment: Yes. Thanks. What I'd like to do is add that image to my project so I can use it in my custom view. Is that possible?

Comment: Simply screenshot an `UITableView` with the `UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert` button. The screenshot above was taken at retina resolution. Now you can use the button in any fashion you like, assuming the background is white.